# MySQL to get the count of rows for each worker with specific dates and jobs

Tags: mysql

I have a database of workers and their assigned work items. I want to create a report using MySQL that will show a count of how many work items under certain jobs and within certain date ranges each worker has. The resulting data would look something like this:

```
           Today          Tomorrow        Next Year
Worker | Job1 Job2 Job3 | Job1 Job2 Job3 | Job1 Job2 Job3

Bob    |  4    0   1    | 1    2    0    | 5    10   3
```

I have one table with the following relevant fields: worker, date, jobtype, workitem

Each worker has multiple entries under the same name, so Bob would have multiple workitems assigned to him, like this:

```
Bob | 07/27/2011 | sandblasting | workitem001
Bob | 08/30/2011 | mowing | workitem001
Bob | 08/30/2011 | driving | workitem002
```

Workitems can be assigned to multiple jobtypes.

I wrote some confusing loops with multiple queries, but ideally I want to write a single, complex query to accomplish this. Is that even possible?

Comment: It's likely possible, but for more of an answer, we'll need to know the table layout or schema.

Comment: your question is not entirely clear. Do you want counts per worker? The relationships in your tables are not clear. Please specify the table definitions.

Comment: I added some more information.

Comment: its possible, but it'll be a very ugly query where you have to join the same tables many times. Is there a fixed number of job types?

Comment: Yes! There are only four job types.

Comment: This is not a good design IMHO. Prefer retrieving simple rows from the db then using app code to render it. btw, I have never seen a report that looks like this, let alone a query. Perhaps a re-think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

overview for each day:

```
select worker, date, job, count(*) as count
from workitems
group by worker, date, job
```

overview for month/year:

```
select worker, month(date) as month, job, count(*) as count
from workitems
group by worker, month, job
```

That's it. The table format is little different as in mysql you cannot put values as columns (job1, job2, job3 in your example), as it is possible with e.g. MS Access' cross query. But you can export the data from mysql with the above queries and then e.g. use MS Excel contingency tables to produce the output you want.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. I'm a lot closer now. I'm writing this in VB.NET application, but I might be able to export to Excel, or integrate Excel.